# How to share data once an activity has started from another function?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I would like know how to send a command to an activity which has started from inside another function. More precisely I want to send a pause intent to com.google.vr:sdk... the view is started like this:

```
class VRPlayer {

    private void playVideo(int sourceType, Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, VrVideoActivity.class);
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void pauseVideo(Context context, JSONArray args) {
        VrVideoActivity.class.toggleVideoPlay(); <------------- NOT WORKING ¯\_(-_- )_/‾
    }

}
```

once the activity has started there should be a way to execute other function, ex: `toggleVideoPlay()` which are inside the `VrVideoAcitivity` from the  but I can't get the right way to do it... If you want to try it you can find the Android project here: https://github.com/StarStep/android-help-vr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
VrVideoActivity vrVideoActivity = new VrVideoActivity();
vrVideoActivity.toggleVideoPlay();
```

a simple way -> `(new VrVideoActivity).toggleVideoPlay();`

another way -> set the `toggleVideoPlay();` to static as following

```
public static void toggleVideoPlay()
{
//Your Code
}
```

and call it `VrVideoActivity.toggleVideoPlay();`

Comment: I've been looking for it for several hours now... :'D I'm a web dev actually

Comment: Yea , faced the same problem in the beginning , hard to figure out.